# CI: Ion Auth Error randomly appears sometimes and I can't figure out why

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I get the following error when using Ion Auth with Code Igniter 2.0 and PHP 5.2

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Practice::$ion_auth
SYSDIR/core/Model.php [ 50 ]
```

and here is the code of that line:

```
45      * @access private
46      */
47     function __get($key)
48     {
49         $CI =& get_instance();
50         return $CI->$key;
51     }
52 }
53 // END Model Class
54 
55 /* End of file Model.php */
```

The weird part about this bug is that it seems to creep up when I attempt to access a page that is ‘restricted’ without first having gone to a non-restricted page on the same domain first. That is to say, if I open my browser and type in example.com/restricted - i get the error. But if I type in example.com/login and THEN (even if i dont log in properly) go to example.com/restricted it will either let me in or redirect me correctly (depending on if i actually logged in).

I can't figure out for the life of me what it is that is triggering this problem. Here is an example of the constructors for some of my controllers using Ion Auth Library:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('firephp');

        //ION
        $this->load->library('Ion_auth');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->database();
    }
```

and

```
class Practice extends CI_Controller {

    var $user;
    var $game;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // ION Auth
        $this->load->library('Ion_auth');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('session');

        // Defaults
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('firephp');

        // Models
        //$this->load->model('Ion_auth_model');
        //$this->load->model('Player');
        $this->load->model('Practice_Game');



        // User must be logged in to use this controller
        // If user is logged in then we get his info as a class variable
        if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
            $this->user = $this->ion_auth->get_user($this->session->userdata('user_id'));
        } else {
```

Comment: You can try submitting this as an issue on Github (in case it's a bug) as the author seems pretty active and may get back to you quicker than an answer from here. https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/issues

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The problem occurs when a remembered login is being autologged in and ion auth tries to use some not yet loaded properties.

You can look at this pull request and the following commit:

https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/pull/46
https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/commit/ba6d09299cd7469835ab3ad7fb1a4333de88d468